# Flask application fails after updated Azure service plan

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-2015, flask

I have a flask application running on Azure. It has been running just fine until I updated the Azure service plan from "D1 Shared" to "S1 Standard".

When trying to access the application, I get the follow error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Couldn't find type for class
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Couldn't find type for class
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Couldn't find type for class
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.]
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type
>   baseType, String initializeData) +6967379
>   System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() +45
>   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() +83
>   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() +142 
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners() +185
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message) +119
>   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String message) +9
>   Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots.SnapshotHelper.RestoreSnapshot(String
>   options) +359
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +160
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +101    System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams) +2026
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.RestorePortableCompilationOutputSnapshot()
>   +10008589    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +18    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

I've tried to change the service plan back to "D1 Shared", then the application runs fine once again.

I have seen a lot of posts all saying to make sure that the solution has a reference to the "Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Diagnostics.dll". I have tried to do this by "Right click" -> "References" -> "Add Reference..." -> ".NET" -> "Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Diagnostics". When I publish again I can see the dll in the "bin" folder. But I still get the same error.

Am I making the reference in the wrong way? If so, how do I do it correctly.

Is there anything else I should do to make my solution work with "S1 Standard"?

Comment: There are two resolved SO threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200782/azure-flask-http-error-500-0-internal-server-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236008/azure-python-web-app-internal-server-error which get the similar issue with yours. Please try to refer to them and check whether exists the same issue for your app. Any update, please let me know.

Comment: The two threads you are referencing to are not the same issue. Both of them get "Internal Server Error", which means that the application has crashed. In my case, the application is running, but not when I upgrade the Azure Service Plan, then I get an error due to a missing dll file (which I cannot seem to add/include in the correct way). But thanks for your comment anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

Disable the Dynamic Cache by going to the **Azure Portal -> Application Settings** and then setting the value of **'WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE' to '0'** (zero).

After completing these steps try to scale up your pricing tier from Shared to Standard.
[image]