# Fail to deploy to Azure a simple django webapp that works well on local machine

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I have a simple Django webapp that works like a charm on my machine. However, when I tried to publish it to Azure Webapp using VS 2015 (by right click the project then click Publish button), it turns out a run time error:

[image]

Then I tried to fix by add "**< customErrors mode="Off"/>**" to the **web.config** file. It turns out another error:

    `Server Error in '/' Application.
    Couldn't find type for class 
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, 
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ..`

I tried the [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/) and [this](http://www.fatlemon.co.uk/2014/01/setting-up-django-on-windows-azure-websites/) tutorial but they do not help. I do not know whether these documents are out of date of not.

Please save my day.

Update: 
I am not sure which log file to post as I am new to Azure. Here is what in file eventlog.xml:

```
<Data>D:\home\site\wwwroot\</Data>
<Data>RD0003FF2899E0</Data>
<Data/>
<Data>9328</Data>
<Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
<Data>IIS APPPOOL\DjangoWebProject220170522042402</Data>
<Data>TargetInvocationException</Data>
<Data>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.RestorePortableCompilationOutputSnapshot()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Couldn't find type for class Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType, String initializeData)
   at System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject()
   at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject()
   at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)
   at Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots.SnapshotHelper.RestoreSnapshot(String options)

</Data>
            <Data>http://djangowebproject220170522042402.azurewebsites.net/handler.fcgi/</Data>
            <Data>/handler.fcgi/</Data>
            <Data>62.177.198.5</Data>
            <Data/>
            <Data>False</Data>
            <Data/>
            <Data>IIS APPPOOL\DjangoWebProject220170522042402</Data>
            <Data>21</Data>
            <Data>IIS APPPOOL\DjangoWebProject220170522042402</Data>
            <Data>False</Data>
            <Data>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.RestorePortableCompilationOutputSnapshot()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
</Data>
```

And DetailErrors files:

```
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request.
The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and 
what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>     
<li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or 
application. 
This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>    <li>IIS 
was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>     
<li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   
<li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility 
Feature is not installed.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div>
```

Comment: The two documents are not out of date. The error of `Couldn't find type for class 
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener` is not explicit & clear for finding out the real reason. Please post more error details and some related codes for helping resolving the issue.

Comment: Meanwhile, there are some similar SO threads which you can follow the exisiting answers to try to resolve yours, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630361/flask-application-fails-after-updated-azure-service-plan, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236008/azure-python-web-app-internal-server-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200782/azure-flask-http-error-500-0-internal-server-error. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I update more detail logs in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630361/flask-application-fails-after-updated-azure-service-plan) threads and it worked:

> Disable the Dynamic Cache by going to the Azure Portal -> Application
>   Settings and then setting the value of '**WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE**' to '**0**'
>   (zero).